# C# for loop - How do I run the loop body with different variables?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have several double type variables who for example are named like this: Hight1, Hight2, Hight3, Hight4, ...
The values are in no order and can be all over the place but the variables are all numbered chronologically.

Now I want to access the value of those variables and run some code until some condition is met. 
For example:

```
bool Result = false;

if (0,3 + Hight1 >= 2)
{
    Result = true;
}
else
{
    if (0,3 + Hight2 >= 2)
    {
        Result = true;
    }
    else
    ...
```

Now I am pretty new to coding and completely self taught and I just found out about for loops and wanted to make a loop for this since this can go on for dozen of variables and can take up hundreds of lines of code which is quite ugly...
So I want to make something like this:

```
bool result = false
for (int i = 1; result!; i++)
{
    if (0,3 + ("Hight" + i) >= 2)
    {
       result = true;
    }
}
```

So in the first round the loop should use Hight1, in the second round Hight2 and so on until some condition is met or we have run through alle the variables.

I just can't find out how to code this. I have looked into reflectors and arrays but have only found examples for how to give those chronologically numbered variables some value+i but not how to access them in a chronological order.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, is the amount Hight variables fixed? meaning it stops at 4? or are there any number of Hight variables?

Comment: Hello, for now I am working with a fixed number of variables.

Comment: Sorry for late response, i see alot of answers have been posted, do you still need some help?

Comment: No problem, thanks for the reply. I made the code work with the help of the other answers :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make `Height` an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

Something like this:

```
var result = false;
decimal[] height = { 0.1, 0.2 }; // use your values here
for (var ii = 0; ii < height.Length; ii++) {
  if (0.3 + height[ii] > 2) {
    result = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Arrays and lists

Whenever you deal with variables with a numbered suffix, nine times out of ten you should be using an array or a list. So instead of:

```
float height1 = 0.1;
float height2 = 1.8;
```

You do:

```
float[] heights = new float[] { 0.1, 1.8 };

//OR

List<float> heights = new List<float>() { 0.1, 1.8 };
```

Which allows you to use loops to process all elements of the array/list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < heights.Length; i++) // use heights.Count for a List<float>
{
    // do something with heights[i]
}
```

Note that for processing each element of a collection, you can instead use a `foreach`, which means you don't have to manually juggle the index value:

```
foreach(var height in heights)
{
    // do something with height
}
```

You can also use LINQ here, which I will get to.

---

### Evaluation logic

I'm not sure why you're doing this:

```
0.3 + height >= 2
```

instead of the more sensical:

```
height >= 1.7
```

There are cases where it makes sense to write out a calculation (e.g. when expressing a timespan in milliseconds), but this doesn't seem to be one of those cases.
This is just an educated guess though, I can't know for a fact if it makes sense in your case to explicitly express 2 and 0.3 as numbers by themselves (it depends on your domain). However, the answer will continue under the assumption that 1.7 is equally meaningful. If it isn't, then you can substitute your original evaluation back into the code samples provided.

Whenever you deal with logic of this shape:

```
if( a == b )
{
    myBoolean = true;
}
else
{
    myBoolean = false;
}
```

This can **always** be reduced to:

```
myBoolean = (a == b);
```

Your logic is slightly different because you have a fallback evaluation, but the same principle applies here, giving you:

```
result = (height1 >= 1.7) || (height2 >= 1.7);
```

`result` will be `true` only if either of the heights is 1.7 or more.

That being said, if you start using an array, this logic isn't necessary anymore, but I wanted to point it out anyway as it dramatically improves readability and it's a basic skill you should improve to become a better developer.

---

### LINQ

I'm going to skip the full introduction (you can find tutorials online), but what LINQ does for you is essentially give you premade loop functions that perform a particular operation on every element of a collection (list/array).

That's actually what you want here: you want to check every height in the array/list, and you want to know if **any** of these heights pass a specific check (i.e. `>= 1.7`).

I highlighted **any** because the appropriate LINQ method here is called `Any()`. It takes in a lambda method which describes the evaluation that needs to be performed, and it returns a boolean that is true if *at least* one element in the collection passes this evaluation.

Your entire code block can be condensed into:

```
float[] heights = new float[] { 0.1, 1.8 };  // you could use the list as well here

var result = heights.Any(height => height >= 1.7);
```

Now I want to refer back to the optimized logic that we established in the previous section. What LINQ's `Any` method does is essentially the same, except that it repeats the evaluations for each element in the collection.

If your collection contains two elements, `Any` basically does the same as:

```
var result = (heights[0] >= 1.7) || (heights[1] >= 1.7);
```

If your collection contains 5 elements, it does the same as:

```
var result = (heights[0] >= 1.7) || (heights[1] >= 1.7) || (heights[2] >= 1.7) || (heights[3] >= 1.7) || (heights[4] >= 1.7);
```

This is where the power of LINQ (and loops in general) shows itself: your code will work regardless of how many elements there are in the collection, so you don't need to manually handle every individual element yourself.
This will save you a boatload of effort.

I won't delve into the specifics of LINQ and lambda methods, but I highly advise you look this up in a knowledge repository of your choice as it is a powerful tool that will dramatically simplify any collection juggling you otherwise would have to write out manually.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, since it destils the best of both worlds (loops and linq).
However: why is `0.3 + height >= 2` better than `height >= 1.7`? Readability. `0.3` might be a margin or something.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič: I did mention that there are cases where it's better to write out multiple magic numbers - most commonly encountered when expressing a given timespan in milliseconds, but other situations may apply. But this _seems to_ not be the case here, based on the very simple evaluation logic that's being used here. It's not a guarantee, but it is an educated guess. Even then, `0.3 + height` seems to be an unusual structure as opposed to the much more common `height + 0.3`. This is the yoda condition principle: it's technically the same but looks more unusual to most people's eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I went with an array for now but will take a look into LINQ in the future.

Comment: I am thinking about letting the code generate its own variables. 
At the moment I have like 10 variables (height1 to height10) all set to = 0 and when numbers come in they get there values. 
But if I would let the code create a new variable only if he needs a new one, I would not know how many variables I have that i need to include in an array or list.
Is there a way to get all variables that contain a certain string name?

Should look something like this:
List<float> heights = new List<float>() { //all variables that contain "height" };

Comment: @APrioriScience: We're delving into the "you need to look up a tutorial" part here. Generally speaking, arrays are used for fixed-length collections and lists can be dynamically added to without knowing the size in advance. For everything else, you're going to have to find a decent C# tutorial because that can't be elaborated on here.

Comment: @Flater: Thank you, I understand that. Will look more into some basics and will work with a set amount of variables and arrays for now.

Answer (score 4):

I would add your properties in a list or array and use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Something like:

```
List<double> allDoubles = new List<double>() { Hight1, Hight2, ...};
return allDoubles.Any(number => number + 0.3 >= 2);
```

The `Any()` method will return true if any of the items in the list meets the condition.

Comment: You realize, that he just discovered loops right? Maybe your solution is a little bit complicated for complete beginner.

Comment: Nice! Better than using loop.

Comment: @ZigaBenko: You're right that beginners will struggle with more advanced concepts, but StackOverflow uses its questions and answers as future knowledge resources. Only allowing for beginner-friendly code is going to generate a biased answer that wouldn't apply in similar scenarios when another person (with a different skill level) is asking the same question and gets referred back here. This answer is a correct and contemporary answer to the question at hand. OP may need to brush up on some skills but it doesn't invalidate the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will give Linq a try!

Answer (score 1):

The way you started doing it is the wrong one. A better approach in this situation is to use a list or an array.

```cs
bool result = false;
double[] array = new double[] { High1, High2, High3 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (0.3 + array[i] > 2)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    } 
}
```

You can simplify the loop a little bit by using [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) instead of for

```cs
bool result = false;
double[] array = new double[] { High1, High2, High3 };

foreach (double item in array)
{
    if (0.3 + item > 2)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can further simplify the loop by using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

```cs
using System.Linq;

double[] array = new double[] { High1, High2, High3 };
bool result = array.Any(item => item + 0.3 >= 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 
I went with an array for now but will try foreach and LINQ in the future.